# How to add bluetooth menu to login window?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, menu-bar

I have a bluetooth mac keyboard which I'm trying to use between two macs. I also have two dedicated mice for each machine. How can I connect (takeover) the keyboard from the login window, in order to type my password to logon?

**Basically, I want this menu...**

[image: Menu bar w/Bluetooth]

**...on this screen.**

[image: Login window's menu bar w/o Bluetooth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  It's not designed this way.

First off, the Mac keyboards aren't designed to have multiple pairings.  If you want to swap between two machines, you need a [keyboard and mouse with that capability](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399830/119271).  The same thing goes for the mouse.

Secondly, allowing the ability to do a Bluetooth pairing *outside* of an authenticated session is a **major** security flaw.  This would allow an attacker to install any sort of device, including nefarious ones, without your consent.  It's more than likely that in *your* use case scenario that would never happen because it's "just you" in your environment, but computer manufacturers don't implement security in one off environments.